# How to set an object reference

Tags: vb.net

I am not sure how to set an object reference to `frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle`?? I am using win7 and vb.net 2008

```
frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle=new frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle???             

            'error object reference not set ....
            xpos = frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle.Left
            ypos = frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle.Top
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the xpos, and ypos?

Comment: You need to instantiate the object before you can reference it.  IE something has never been made new or  set to something.

Answer (score 3):

Object reference not set to an instance of an object means that you're trying to access some member of an uninstantiated object. What that means is that you forgot to create the object (via `new`).

In your case, you're probably trying to use `frmD` or `Picture1` before it has been created.

Comment: I updated my question, I believe I am missing something within `frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle=new frmD.Picture1.ClientRectangle`

Comment: No, you shouldn't be doing it like that, ClientRectangle is supposed to be provided by the PictureBoxControl (or whatever it is you're using). Is there a chance you're calling this code before the form is loaded?

Comment: No, because I am loading the form first with the following statement `Dim frmD As New frmMain` and other processes are performed before where my issue occurs.

Comment: This "Dim frmD As New frmMain" doesn't load the form it simply instatitates it.  You need a Show or ShowDialog to Load the form.